# How to make list show in a proper columns and row in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My list of BlogPost can't show in a proper way that I want it to display. I want it to display two rows of Blogpost on each line. it's doing that but my Blogpost list has become smaller. I don't know what I am doing wrong. another thing, I am struggling to show a list properly in a row after looping through the Blogpost.

I am working on MERN stack. The first image is what I want but the second image is what I am getting.

```
  const Post = props => (
     <div>
    
        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-aos="fade- 
           right">
           <div className="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
             <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/39811/pexels-photo- 
               39811.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="" width="100%" 
               />
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
            <div className="blog-column">
                <span>{props.post.title}</span>
                <ul className="blog-detail list-inline"> 
                    <li><i className="fa fa-user" />{props.post.from}</li> 
                    <li><i className="fa fa-clock-o" />{props.post.createdAt} 
                    </li> 
                </ul> 
                <p>{props.post.description}</p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
 
)



  

 postList() {
     return this.state.posts.map(function(currentPost, i) {
        return <Post post={currentPost} key={i} />;
     });
  }







render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="blog">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">  
                            <h2><span className="ion-minus" />Blog Posts<span className="ion-minus" /></h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis  dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus </p><br />
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-aos="fade-right">
                            {this.postList() }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is what I want:

[image: But this is what I want]

This is the what I am getting:

[image: This is the what I am getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div className="row">
   <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-aos="fade-right">
       {this.postList() }
   </div>
</div>
```

If you want full width for any screen, you need to specify '*-12' in place of '*-6' like in this case: col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12